# Possible to parse a folder-location to find instances of certain characters in BATCH?

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop

I have a .bat file and I'm trying to parse through each character in a Folder Location String, in order to count the occurrences of a certain character.

How could I do that in a .bat file?

Is it possible using a FOR loop where you perform code similar to this?:

```
FOR /F %%i in (%cd%) DO (IF %%i =="w" counter+=1)
```

I know the above isn't correct, I'm just starting out.

Haven't managed to find the answer in my research so far.

Answer (score 0):

either work with substrings (look at every character), which is slow with longer strings or count the words and count the words when you replace each `"w"` with `" w"`. The difference is the count of `w` (it ignores capitalization, so it counts `w` plus `W`):

```
@echo off
set "string=Hello beautiful World"
for /f %%A in ('(for %%a in (%string%^) do @echo %%a^)^|find /c /v ""') do set A=%%A
for /f %%A in ('(for %%a in (%string:l= l%^) do @echo %%a^)^|find /c /v ""') do set B=%%A
set /a count=B-A
echo --- %count%
```

Reason for not just removing the spaces is that `for` standard delimiters is not just space, but space, tab, comma, ...

Note: this does not take care of poison characters.